# Fitnesse in Cruisecontrol.net exec: do not fail the build when tests fail

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, fitnesse, acceptance-testing

I'm trying to integrate fitnesse with our cruisecontrol setup.

I'd like to have a set of acceptance tests that we develop before the features for the release are worked on. Develop our acceptance tests, run them against our nightly build (not on every check in, we have a job for that but I suspect our acceptance tests would slow that down too much).

So I want to be able to run the fitnesse test suite and not have it fail the build when some tests fail (the expectation is that some of the tests will fail, until we have finished the release).

I have the acceptance tests building on the integration server and the the fitnesse suite running from the command line (as an exec task in the integration job).

At the moment it is failing the build (runner.exe has a non-zero exit code when any test fails).

So... does anyone have a list of exit codes for fitsharp runner.exe? Is there any way to tell a cruisecontrol exec task that I really don't care about the return value from the job? Is there another cc.net task I should use instead?

**Edit:**
Current best idea is to wrap the fitsharp runner in a batch file or powershell script and swallow the return code from fitness
**Edit2:**
Return code from fitsharp runner.exe is the number of tests that failed (making setting the success return codes element for the cruisecontrol.net exec task difficult)

Comment: the ignore output from exec task is covered in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828513/how-to-ignore-output-from-executable-with-cruisecontrol-net-build.

Comment: Have you checked out: http://amalkov.blogspot.com/2010/01/just-test.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is with nant, which integrates very nicely with ccnet. You can simply tell a nant exec task to not fail the build, see http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/exec.html
When you're close to release, simply set the failonerror property to true.